# How can I save data from Android service?

Tags: android, save, android-service

I have a service that collects data, can I save the data in case of reboot or any other action that will restart the service, and how can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can I save the data in case of reboot or any other action that will restart the service

You will not necessarily find out when those sorts of events will occur. Save your data as you go.

> And how can I do it?

Use a file. Or a database, which is a type of file. Or a `SharedPreferences` structure, which is backed by a type of file.

Comment: Can I use SharedPreferences for complex objects?

Comment: @Alex Kapustian: Not really. It is designed for user settings -- strings, integers, booleans, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to make use of Android's SQLite3 support, which provides you with a lightweight relational database on the handset where you can store your data. For an introduction (as well as some other options), see: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 1):

Or use the serialization API

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/

Answer (score 0):

Android Services have a lifecycle like its Activities.  Refer to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle) for proper callbacks to save state before a service is shutdown.

Might I recommend the [onDestroy()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onDestroy%28%29) method.

Comment: OnDestroy() might not be called if the service is killed by the system due to low memory.

Comment: IME `onDestroy()` won't get called if the service is killed by the system due to low memory