# How can I save a number on the user's phone to be accessed later?

Tags: android, save

I am currently developing an app that keeps track of how many time you do something. I want the data to be saved so that when the app is closed and reopened, the same data will come back to be added onto. The data is for the user's long term use so the app will close eventually, but I need the data (2 counters) to be saved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I save data from android service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564591/how-can-i-save-data-from-android-service). Also [How to save data in an android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962344/how-to-save-data-in-an-android-app).

Answer (score 2):

You can use SharedPreferences to save the counters and can edit it every time the user reopen the Application.

Please read the following:

[Use of SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698490/what-is-the-use-of-shared-preferences-in-android)

[How to use SharedPreference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851560/how-to-use-sharedpreferences)

[Continuing integer counter from sharedpreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068986/continuing-integer-counter-from-sharedpreferences)

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways of storing data in android:

- [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)
- SQLite database
- physical file in external storage

In your case I would suggest using SharedPreferences, because it is recommended for all key-value settings in android apps.